# Finding reachable vertices of a vertex in a graph

Tags: python, graph

I am having problem in my code to calculate the reachable vertices in a graph.

I have the following code for the graph

```
class Vertices():
    number = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Vertices.number += 1
        self.number = Vertices.number
        self.Reachable= []
```

I create the graph in the following way

```
a = Vertices()
a.Reachable = [1,2]
b = Vertices()
b.Reachable = [3]
c = Vertices()
c.Reachable= [3]
List = []
List.append(a)
List.append(b)
List.append(c)
```

Thus vertex 1 that is *a* has an edge to itself and *b* . Similarly for *b* and for *c*.

We can move around the graph using List i.e. for vertex *a* it is reachable to List[trans-1] where *trans* refers to the `Reachable list of a (List[0] and List[1])`

Now in this graph I have to calculate the reachability for each vertex i.e. for each vertex calculate the vertices that it can reach. For example *a* can reach *a,b* and *c*

I have read that I can use sets to do depth first search in all the list. Can you provide me a solution as to how to proceed.

Can anyone tell me how to use sets as I think that it is quite ideal for this problem seeing that it has union and difference functions associated with it....
PS : This isn't a school based assignment.....

Comment: you get more attention when you tag your question with relevant tags

Comment: you shouldn't be using lists to store vertices as you can add the same vertex multiple times which is error-prone. In dictionary all keys are unique.

Comment: @matcheek How do you define same vertex .... I can have in dictionary { 'A' : ['B','C'] ,'B' : ['B','C'] } which is same as that of storing 2 vertices in a list having same reachable vertices

Comment: @user506710: notice that you can do: List.append(a), some_operations_on_a(a), List.append(a) and your list will have two vertices of 'a' with different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [well-known solution](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) to your problem?

First, you need a data structure for a graph. You can do it as dictionary of lists where each vertex is represented as the key and reachable vertices are the list values.

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['C', 'D'],
         'C': ['D'],
         'D': ['C'],
         'E': ['F'],
         'F': ['C']}
```

If you represent your graph as shown above, finding the neighbouring vertices of B would be just

```
neighbours_of_B = graph['B']
```

and (from the same site)
finding all paths without cycles would be:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

and run it as:

```
find_all_paths(graph, 'A', 'D')
```

hope that helps.
Read more about it at the above link.

Comment: +1 @matcheek, I know this isn't your code, but I want to save some people headaches in the future.  path = [] in the signature should never be done. The mutable gets defined at the module level and is shared by all calls to the function.  Luckily in this case it is never mutated but copied on the first line. None or (), tuples being immutable are good candidates for signatures.

Comment: @kevpie: "Never" is a little strong. Obviously you can get away with making the default value of ad argument a mutable when you know what you're doing, and in fact sometimes it's done quite intentionally.

Comment: @martineau: Apologies, you are right, it is too strong. It likely should have read `should almost never`.  It is such a classic mistake if it is not intentional.  Whenever I see it I just expect it trip someone up somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) or any other graph library?

Your current representation won't work. How is any function supposed to go from the number `2` to the vertice `b` ? You need to add the actual object, not just their number.

Once you did that you can do something like this:

```
def reachable( start ):
    # the set of reachable nodes
    reachable = set()

    # recursive function to add all reachable nodes to `reachable`
    def finder(node):
        reachable.add(node.)
        for other in node.Reachable:
            finder(other)

    # add everything we can reach from here
    finder(start)
    return reachable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I don't want to use any third library for it .... And as for 2 to b that could be done via a dictionary. I was actually looking for a solution for sets but thanks a lot...

Comment: @user506710: Storing the actual object is much better than a dictionary. I have no idea what you mean by "a solution for sets"

Comment: I don't get it why if I am storing in a list and can use List[2-1] for b is a dictionary important. Since I am storing the objects in a list and can get to other object just using indexes. I meant using sets in Python http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

Answer (score -1):

Well first off it's `Vertex`, not `Vertice`. Secondly, you have (approximately) implemented an   [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) as the data structure for your graph; it would be more standard to use an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

Do you know what [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) is? Roughly, you start at a vertex and pick a neighbour, then pick a neighbour of that, and so on until you run out of neighbours to pick. Then you backtrack and pick the next neighbour, and so on. It is elegantly implemented recursively (have you come across that before?), because the problem can easily be separated into smaller pieces: to search a graph depth-first you simply start from any vertex and then depth-first search from all its neighbours in turn.

Concretely, you need to break the problem into smaller problems: suppose you can find the nodes reachable from `b` and `c`. What can you reach from `a`? Well, `b`, everything reachable from `b`, `c`, and everything reachable from `c`.

Comment: Hey , Thanks a lot for your answer but I know what recursion is and depth first search is .... I was looking for an answer as to how to use sets of Python in this particular problem. Thanks a lot anyways....